# Googlesheet script to copy range only if it is not empty or error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy certain range from other sheet (or the same one) but only copy it if the range is not empty or have an error message like (#N/A, #REF, etc.).

For example:

- Sheet 1: Contains the original data sheet.
- Sheet 2: Contains the copied data from the script, but the data here only overwritten if the original ones are not empty or errored.

```
function test() {  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet2').getRange('A2').setValue('=QUERY(sheet1!A2:E355, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E LIMIT 200",1)')
}
```

Note: I used QUERY here to copy, but I'm sure it's not the best for copying, as it doesn't retain the value in the other sheet, but just to demonestrate.

Comment: Should the script check the range cell by cell, and copy only the non-empty, non-error cells, or it should not copy any cell in the range if a single empty/error cell is found?

Comment: Your question does NOT provide enough information. First: The range is "A2:E355"=5 columns, 354 rows, 1770 cells. But you say _only copy it if the range is not empty or have an error message_ What does this mean??: 1) If any of the 1770 cells is empty or error, then do not copy anything?, or 2) if any cell is blank or error, then do not copy that cell? , or 3) something else? Second: Do not copy if a cell is blank... why not? - it will just copy a blank cell to a blank cell UNLESS Sheet2 already has content, and a blank cell would overwrite the existing content. So, what content is on Sheet2

Comment: Iamblichus @Tedinoz Sorry if it's not clear. to make it clear,  if the range has empty cells **AND** error message (#ref or any error), then no copy, if the range has any empty cells or rows without errors, the script can still copy it. Here is a sheet may better explain it [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WmwSFxrMnZVOCCVOjXTJGN-dFCIgldrOseQI6UrsMGU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Iamblichus in case you didn't see it

Comment: So really, the reference to an empty cell is irrelevant; just don't copy if ANY cell has an error.

Comment: What to do in these two situations: (1) the range has empty **rows** (and not the last ones in the range), and (2) there are no empty cells, but there is an error in a cell. Also, is the source range always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy your range to another sheet if the following conditions are met:

- The source range does not contain any cell with an error.
- All empty rows in the source range (if any) are located at the end of the range (there is no row with values after an empty row).

If that's correct, you could do the following (check inline comments):

```js
function copyRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source_sheet"); // Source sheet name
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("target_sheet"); // Target sheet name
  var A1notation = "C6:E23"; // A1 notation of the source range (please change if necessary)
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(A1notation);
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var errors = ["#REF!", "#N/A", "#DIV/0!", ...]; // Array of errors (incomplete)
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) { // Iterate through all values in source range
    for (var j = 0; j < sourceValues[i].length; j++) {
      if (errors.includes(sourceValues[i][j])) return; // End execution if error found in a cell
    }
  }
  // Check if there is an inbetween empty row:
  var emptyRowInBetween = sourceValues.map(rowValues => { 
    return rowValues.every(cellValue => {
      return cellValue === "";
    });
  }).join().indexOf("true,false") !== -1;
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("A1"); // Range to copy to (please change if necessary)
  if (!emptyRowInBetween) sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange); // Copy range to specified destination
}
```

#### Update:

If you only want to copy the values, and not the formulas, etc., you can do this:

```js
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
```

#### Note:

- You have to [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) for this to work.

#### Reference:

- [Range.copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

Comment: Thanks! @Iamblichus, it's as I what I meant, just one thing I probably failed to mention, sorry, it doesn't overwrite the target data if I rerun the script and the conditions are true, for example, if a cell E6 changed from "orange" to "banana" in the source sheet, if I rerun the script, it doesn't overwrite it, the same with an empty cell, if for example cell D10 in the source sheet changed from value "10" to an empty value, I  would like if I run the script, overwrite the value "10" to an empty cell in the target sheet, and that applies to whole range, how can I do it?

Comment: @lad I don't know what makes you think otherwise, but this code overwrites the previous data if the conditions are met. Please double-check that.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I feet stupid now! One question though, If I want to copy the values only, ie, not copying the equations or any other attributes, how to do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Iamblichus. I have a question that may sound stupid, one of the error messages I wrote was "Loading..." to prevent the copy of the data still loading, however, unlike other error messages, it does copy it regardless, any idea why? Is it a reserved text in googlesheet? I went further and tested the text "Loading..." with REGEXEXTRACT, results were like a real error messege and it turned to be like actually loading data (the red arrow), even though it's just a text!

Comment: @lad I guess "Loading..." is not an error, so the value of the cell is not "Loading...". I'd suggest you to (1) get the value of this cell with `getValue()`, and (2) see if there is any pattern in this value (and the values you reasonably expect) so that you can detect and filter these values (and not copy ranges that contain these). I hope my explanation was useful. If you have problem with this, I'd suggest you to create another question for this issue.