# Googlesheet script to copy range but not while source data loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following a question I asked before on copying a range from source to target here [Googlesheet script to copy range only if it is not empty or error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783578/googlesheet-script-to-copy-range-only-if-it-is-not-empty-or-error/60851438?noredirect=1#comment107685811_60851438)

The script working as intended, but one issue is if the source data is being loaded (usually googlesheet presents a message "Loading..."), the script still copy the range, which is empty, and overwrite the target range, rendering the script useless.
I tried to include the "Loading..." as an error message to not copy the range if it exists, but that didn't work either.

How prevent the data copy if during the script execution the source range is being loaded?

Comment: This is due to a too large load of cell functions. Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: The sheet itself isn't that big, probably ~300 rows only, and the source sheet does import the data from external googlesheet (not that big as well) using IMPORTDATA and run every 4 hours. Unfortunately, I can't share it, as it may contain sensitive information, but I can recreate a dummy one if necessary. I use this method as I don't want to work directly on the external sheet that contains the original data, so I import it, then make a copy using that script, however, that "Loading..." issue is what I can't solve.

Comment: That's odd, does the function work in a single cell in a separate Sheet? A dummy would be useful as you said.